# how to get AWS IOT MQTT ping stats

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, ping, iot

[image: Aws iot mqtt ping stats]

How do I get aws iot mqtt ping stats like life style events? AWS IOT Dashboard reports them in messages as a type. Similar to Connect, Ping, Publish, Subscribe. I’d like to know each ping latency by clientid

I can get lifecycle events by creating a IOT rule similar to

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/topics.html

```
SELECT *,  topic() as Topic,  clientid() as ClientID, accountid() as AccountID, principal() as Principal, traceid() as TraceID FROM '$aws/events/#'

{
    "clientId": "mqtt-explorer-48606",
    "timestamp": 1501188384737,
    "eventType": "disconnected",
    "clientInitiatedDisconnect": false,
    "sessionIdentifier": "da3dd0f6-1c45-4dd-ae2d-ac0b01dd98c",
    "principalIdentifier": "26dd6172d/AROd7C:CognitontityCredentials/ARdCOdVWSKdU7LdC:CognitoIdentityCredentials",
    "Topic": "$aws/events/presence/disconnected/mqtt-explorer-48606",
    "ClientID": "N/A",
    "AccountID": "269986",
    "Principal": "26dd6172d/AROd7C:CognitoIdentityCredentials/AROAJCO5QQVWSKLHU7L7C:CognitoIdentityCredentials",
    "TraceID": "380c8dfc-cc79-9c58-7e27-61566788"
}
```